# Jest api bulk update to ES

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I have huge number of documents that has to be indexed to `Elasticsearch` everyday. I tried with 50,000 records using `JEST` client. But the bulk operation fails after indexing 5000 or so records.

Is it possible to bulk update say 200K records in single operation using `JEST` bulk update API ?

```
        for(Log log : logs) {
            Index temp = new Index.Builder(log).index(index).type(type).build();
            list.add(temp);
        }

        // to bulk import
        Bulk bulkupdate = new Bulk.Builder().addAction(list).build();
        BulkResult finalresult = client.execute(bulkupdate);
```

**error**: Jest `HttpClient` socket read timeout error

Answer (score 0):

Increase connection and read timeouts for the IR client being used.

Comment: already tried. doesn't help. I run cURL instead of Jest just for bulk updates.